# How to change settings for Win10 File Explorer's "Frequent Folders"

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I use the File Explorer's Quick Access "Frequent Folders" section a lot but it seems to take a while before a folder will appear there.  Is there a way to change the setting so folders will appear sooner?  I know how to pin folders but that's not what I want to do.

EDIT:  For example, there's clearly some default setting that tells Explorer to add a folder to the Frequent Folder section after X clicks (or other events).  Is there a way--via a setting, the registry, a freeware utility--to change X to Y?

Comment: Open File Explorer, right click on Quick Access and select Options. You can show Files or Folders or Both in QA but not control the order.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was there. But it doesn't resolve my question.  I added a clarification to my original post.